# Equivalente en java de esta línea de código en C#

Tags: java, c#, sql, array

- Este es mi código `C#`
  Quisiera poder adaptarlo a `Java` solo la parte que esta en el `IF`

  ```
     internal void getCliente(clsCliente e_cliente)
      {
          string bd = "Cinestar", comando = "usp_getCliente                        "+e_cliente.idCliente;

       SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=" + bd + ";Integrated Security=True");
          SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(comando, cn);
          SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
          DataTable dt = new DataTable();
          da.Fill(dt);
          if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
          {
              e_cliente.setRegistro(System.Array.ConvertAll(dt.Rows[0].ItemArray, x => x.ToString().Trim()));
          }
      }
  ```
- Mi Clase `ClsCLiente`:

  ```
     class clsCliente
     {
      #region propiedades
      public int idCliente { get; set; }
  public string Nombres { get; set; }
  public string Apellidos { get; set; }
  public string Dni { get; set; }
  public string Contraseña { get; set; }
  public string Genero { get; set; }
  public string FechaNacimiento { get; set; }
  public string Direccion { get; set; }
  public int IdDistrito { get; set; }
  public string Correo { get; set; }
  public bool Eliminado { get; set; }
  public bool valido { get; set; }
  #endregion

  #region Metodos
  public void setRegistro(string [] aRegistro) {
      valido = aRegistro != null;
      if (valido)
      {
          idCliente = int.Parse(aRegistro[0]);
          Nombres = aRegistro[1];
          Apellidos = aRegistro[2];
          Dni = aRegistro[3];
          Contraseña = aRegistro[4];
          Genero = aRegistro[5];
          FechaNacimiento = aRegistro[6];
          Direccion = aRegistro[7];
          IdDistrito = int.Parse(aRegistro[8]);
          Correo = aRegistro[9];
          Eliminado = aRegistro[10] == "true";
      }
  }
  public object[] getRegistro()
  {
      return new object[] { idCliente, Nombres, Apellidos, Dni, Contraseña, Genero, FechaNacimiento, Direccion, IdDistrito, Correo, Eliminado };
  }
    #endregion
  }
  ```

Solo quiero que el método `SetRegistro` Reciba el `Array`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno, en java lo que obtienes al hacer una consulta es un `ResultSet`.

Ahora para revisar sí el objeto viene vacío o no solo tienes que hacer lo siguiente:

```
if (resultSet.next())
{
   //no está vacio
}
```

ahora bien, sí haces esto, el objeto se moverá a la primera, por lo cual, la próxima vez, se moverá a la segunda, por tanto, tienes que llamar al método `beforeFirst()`

```
if (resultSet.next())
{
   //no está vacio
   resultSet.beforeFirst();
}
```

Ahora, para convertir a un array, el resultSet, creo que no existe algún método que haga eso, así que tienes que hacerlo de forma "manual". También podrías usar un `ArrayList`, que resultaría un poco más factible.

```
List arr = new ArrayList();
while(resultSet.next())
{
  arry.add(resultSet.getString("nombreDeLaColumna"));
  arry.add(resultSet.getString("otroNombreDeLaColumna"));
}
```

Con un array de Strings

```
String[] array = new String[n]() //n posiciones
while(resultSet.next())
{
   array[0] = resultSet.getString("Columna0");
   array[1] = resultSet.getString("Columna1");
   array[2] = resultSet.getString("Columna2");
   //así con cada campo de las columnas
}
```